# Spring Boot migration to 2.5/2.6 from 2.1 - Issue with SQL Script DataSource Initialization order

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-2, spring-boot-2.6.0

I'm migrating my existing Spring Boot `2.1.x` application to `2.6.x`. I want the following behavior (for integration tests which uses embedded H2 database), which is working fine in `2.1.x` (obviously) but I'm struggling to achieve the same behavior in `2.6.x`.

1. Create DDL automatically (without any custom SQL script)
2. Execute custom DML (data.sql)
3. Initialize beans which implements `InitializingBean` and use data populated in step #2. Eg. Cache database table records for application to use later

#### Problem #1 (Solved)

`2.6.x` was no longer created DDL automatically by default. So adding below properties explicit seemed to be the solution.

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

This solves *Step #1* with `2.6.x`.

#### Problem #2 (Solved)

Starting from `2.5`, [Boot was running scripts in `data.sql` before Hibernate is initialized](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes). Hence, `data.sql` was failing. To make Boot wait for DDL creation to complete, adding below property seemed to be the solution.

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
```

This solves *Step #2 with `2.6.x`.

#### Problem #3 (Need solution)

Seemingly because of setting `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to `true`, Step #3 is happening before Step #2 i.e. in `2.6.x`. This cause beans to initialize with empty database tables e.g. Cache is populated with no entries. These are causing my tests to fail.

I played with properties like `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization`, `spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode` and `spring.sql.init.mode` to workaround this without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your `InitializingBean` (or the `@Bean` method producing it) with `@DependsOnDatabaseInitialization`. The bean will then only be created or initialized after the database initialization has completed.

Behind the scenes, the annotation will let the bean factory be configured such that your `InitializingBean` depends on any `DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer`, and in particular the one that executes the `data.sql`.

There is more information on this in the official reference documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.15/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.dependencies.depends-on-initialization-detection

Answer (score 0):

You can defer executing those `InitializingBean`'s logic to just after the spring context finish startup by using [`ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.command-line-runner) . At that moment , all beans initialisation , bootstrapping hibernate and executing `data.sql` should already be done.

Something likes:

```java
@Service
public class FooService implements ApplicationRunner {


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        //cache database table records for later use...
    }
}
```

The end result is the same as using `InitializingBean` approach (i.e. After the application startup, the DB records will be cached in that bean)